# Correct ways to manipulate / get information from array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods

I have defined an array of objects for a class `Plane`. Like this:

```
        Plane[] terminalOne = new Plane[] {
            new Plane(1, "Madrid", "Ryanair", "Airbus A300", "05.00"),
            new Plane(3, "Riga", "AirBaltic", "Boeing 737", "05.30")
            //ETC..
        };
```

I'm trying to figure out how to manipulate / get information from this array, for example, display objects. I tried `System.out.println(terminalOne);` which returns `[Lairport.Plane;@322ba3e4` (where airport is my package) I don't understand what this means, but I assume it returned first object? I tried to make it more readable and in my file where I define Plane class and object constructor I added this function:

```
    public void displayPlane() // display plane
    { 
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("{" + flightID + "," + destination + "," + airline + "," + aircraft + "," + time + "}");
        System.out.println();
    }
```

To display information about object in form of `{.., .., .., .., ..}` and tried applying it in my main file as `terminalOne.displayPlane();` However got a compiler error saying "Can not find symbol, symbol: method displayPlane(), location: variable terminalOne of type Plane[]"

I worked with LinkedLists where I defined these methods in a separate file, alongside methods for search, delete etc.. Can I do something like this for arrays, if so what is the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`terminalOne` is an array, not an individual plane. You could use:

```
for (Plane plane : terminalOne) {
    plane.displayPlane();
}
```

... but I would personally consider overriding `toString()` in `Plane` instead:

```
@Override public String toString() {
    return "{" + flightID + "," + destination + "," + airline + "," +
           aircraft + "," + time + "}";
}
```

Then:

```
for (Plane plane : terminalOne) {
    System.out.println(plane);
}
```

Comment: So now, I can create various methods in my Plane class and than use them this way right? Also, is it possible to use this method for several arrays, for example `for(Plane plane : terminalOne && terminalTwo)` (tried this out, doesn't work)

Comment: @Ilja: No, you can't use `&&` to combine lists. But you could use Guava (http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) and use `for (Plane plane : Iterables.concat(terminalOne, terminalTwo))`

Answer (score 0):

as Jon suggested you could replace your `displayPlane()` method with `toString()` implementation.
Then you could call

```
System.out.println("terminalOne = " + Arrays.toString(terminalOne));
```

to see all elemens of your array printed.

to output results from "concatenation" you can then do: 
:

```
List<Plane> concatList = new ArrayList<Plane>();
Collections.addAll(concatList, terminalOne);
Collections.addAll(concatList, terminalTwo);
// add many more terminals and then print
System.out.println(concatList);
```

using only standard java library